# calculated field in sharepoint list

Tags: list-view

I want to create a calculated field in list which should include a view link and starte date. Like in calander when I click view item it should include a `field X (calculated field)` which has url like

```
http:sharepoint/new.aspx?View={guid}&FilterField1=cabmet&FilterValue1=[Startdate]
```

Where `[startdate] = start date of that respective item`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use concatenation to create your calculated column, something along the lines of:

```
="http://sharepoint/new.aspx&view={guid}&FilterField1=cabmet&FilterValue1="&[startdate]
```

Where `[startdate]` is your start date column.

For more calculated column information, see: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Can you provide me full calculated text. I am using below and getting syntax error

=CONCATENATE("http://sharepoint/new.aspx&view={guid}&FilterField1=cabmet&FilterValue1="&[startdate])

Comment: The function 'Concatenate' does not exist in SharePoint, instead you can just use '&'. 
Try it exactly as it is in my answer instead.